# GoogleMap in AlertDialog

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, android-alertdialog

I have a AlertDialog that opens a map with specific coordinates.
It does not work first run properly.
But from the second time it's the following error:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #32: Error inflating class fragment
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:719)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
at com.prodados.comcenter.activity.VendaActivity.popupLocaGPSCliente(VendaActivity.java:999)
at com.prodados.comcenter.activity.VendaActivity.access$23(VendaActivity.java:986)
at com.prodados.comcenter.activity.VendaActivity$8.onItemClick(VendaActivity.java:464)
at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:301)
at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1510)
at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3339)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #32: Duplicate id 0x7f09004e, tag null, or parent id 0xffffffff with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment
at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4971)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:695)
```

[image: Screen with error]

Layout file: cliente_local.xml

```
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment1"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp" />
```

My method method calling a AlertDialog:

```
private GoogleMap mapa;

private void popupLocaGPSCliente1(){
    try {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder;
            AlertDialog alertDialog;
            Context mContext = VendaActivity.this;
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View view = vi.inflate(R.layout.cliente_local, null);   

            LatLng cordGoogleSp = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);                              
            mapa = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment1)).getMap();                  
            mapa.clear();               
            mapa.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(cordGoogleSp));             
            CameraPosition update = new CameraPosition(cordGoogleSp, 15, 0, 0);
            mapa.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(update), 5000, null);              
            mapa.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);    

            builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
            builder.setView(view);
            builder.setNeutralButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {              
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {                    
                    dialog.dismiss();                   
                }
            });
            alertDialog = builder.create();
            alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ico_cliente_local);
            alertDialog.setTitle("Localização do Cliente:");
            alertDialog.show();         

    } catch (Exception e) {
        exibirMensagem("Erro: ", e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your `MapFragment` `(fragment1)` class doesn't inflate try with `SupportMapFragment`

```
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
```

inside Activity

```
FragmentManager myFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
SupportMapFragment  mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) myFragmentManager
            .findFragmentById(R.id.fragment1);

    mapa = mapFragment.getMap();
```